# Android SDK: RelativeLayout - Button WILL NOT center horizontally, even with Layout_CenterHorizontal=true

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout

I really hope somebody can help me here because I am going to start pulling my hair out if this keeps doing what it's doing.

I'm trying to design a layout and I want all of my stuff to be centered. So far, everything is. However, the Save button I created will not center itself for the life of it. It consistently aligns its left edge with the center of the screen, rather than the center of the button itself.

Below is a screenshot of my simple design and the xml behind it...  Any help will be GREATLY appreciated!

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_settings"
    tools:context="com.hypertom.weeklymealgenerator.SettingsActivity"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/strSettingsTitle"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/strSettingsNumMeals"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/strSettingsThresholdMin"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/strSettingsThresholdMax"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/strSettingsNumServings"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/strSettingsNumSubstitutes"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnSettingsSave"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-12dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-12dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-12dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-12dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-12dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? It can be done much easier in LinearLayout though.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="strSettingsTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="# of Meals"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Threshold Min"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Threshold Max"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Num of Servings"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Num of Substitutes"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:text="Save" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, things have been busy at work haha. I won't be able to try your suggestion until Sunday but offhand it looks like this could be what I'm looking for! Potential thanks in advance! I'll report back.